# C++ program on how much a person would earn over time if salary is one penny per day (Not an IT student)

Tags: c++

I have a project to write a program that calculates how much a person would earn over a period of time if his or her salary is one penny the first day, two pennies the second day, and continues to double each day. The program should ask the user for the number of days. Display a table showing how much the salary was for each day, and then show the total pay at the end of the period. The output should be displayed in a dollar amount, not the number of pennies.

Input Validation: Do not accept a number less than 1 for the number of days worked.

This is my code so far and I can't seem to get it to work properly (not an 
IT student)

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<iomanip.h>

int main()
{
    int days;
    double pennies = 0.01;
    double total = 0.0;
    double fixed;
    double showpoint;

    cout << "For how many days will the pay double?";
    cin >> days;

    cout << endl << "Day    Total Pay\n";
    cout << "------------------------\n";

    for (int count = 1; count <= days; count++)
    {
        cout << count << "\t\t$\t" << (pow(2, pennies)) << endl;
    }

    cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << showpoint;
    cout << "--------------------------------\n";
    cout << "Total  $\t" << total << endl;

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you should start studying IT ;) this helps a bit with programming. But it also would help if you can explain what does not work

Comment: What do you mean by `can't seem to get it to work properly`, what doesn't work? Does it fail to compile? Does it give the wrong output for some specific input? Something else?

Comment: @RawN - oh yeah? Can I come work for you for 32 days? Hint: on the last day, you'd pay me $42949672.96 and on the first, just $0.01 - the daily pay-rate is ((2^daynum) / 100) dollars

Comment: @enhzflep In all honesty I didn't bother to read the entire question, just the title. I'll be more careful in the future.

Comment: @RawN - Sorry if you didn't have fun too. No harm, no foul. ;)

Comment: You don't need to study IT very much, but you need to apply highschool maths and common sense - "2 to the power of pennies" is not the *daily* amount you're looking for. You also need to add every daily amount to the total (this does require a little bit of IT study).

Comment: It is difficult to offer solutions when the problem statement is simply, "it doesn't work".  Please [edit] your question to give a more complete description of what you expected to happen and how that differs from the actual results.  See [ask] for hints on what makes a good explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to explain the changes I have made, but if you need to know more please ask

```
// Headers for standard library features don't have .h on the end (normally)
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<iomanip>

int main()
{
    int days = 0;
    // double pennies = 0.01; Not needed.
    double total = 0.0;
    // If you don't initialise variables it will cause a crash or undefined behaviour.
    // double fixed;
    // double showpoint;

    while (days < 1)    // This prevents negative or 0 day contracts.
    {
        // You need to use the full name to cout or that abomination of a command using namespace std
        std::cout << "For how many days will the pay double?";
        std::cin >> days;
    }
    std::cout << std::endl << "Day    Total Pay\n";
    std::cout << "------------------------\n";

    // looping from 0 while less than days is more "normal".
    for (int count = 0; count < days;  count++)
    {
        double payForTheDay = (pow(2, count));
        std::cout << count << "\t\t$\t" << payForTheDay << std::endl;
        total += payForTheDay;  // You need to increment the total.
    }
    // Not sure what this is about
    // std::cout << std::setprecision(2) << fixed << showpoint;
    std::cout << "--------------------------------\n";
    std::cout << "Total  $\t" << total << std::endl;

    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace `(pow(2, pennies))` with `(pennies * pow(2, (count - 1)))`...

Notes:

1. Shouldn't `pennies` actually be named `dollars`?
2. To calculate the `total`, just increase it by the daily salary for each day (e.g. inside the loop where you output each table row).

Comment: Maybe the down voters would care to share an answer of their own..?

Comment: I have to agree with you Obe, there is nothing wrong with what you have said, I can't see why it was down voted.  (You missed the problem with the header files and std though :) )

Answer (score 0):

So look at the basic of the problem. It is basically a geometric progression.

In a geometric progression sum of n numbers is;

```
Sn=a1((1-r^n)/(1-r))
[a1=first element(in your case 1);r=2(in this case)]
```

Use the formula to get number of pennies for n days.
Now convert it into dollar value.

If you need full code comment here.

Comment: I think that your answer is very complex compared to the original post.  Although your answer is correct it isn't a C++ solution to the problem and it doesn't help the OP to learn where they have gone wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Quite late, but using bitwise shift is the best thing for 2^n in my opinion. It's fast and easy to use.

```
int days; // = amount of days for payment;
// Add input/output logic
if (days<1) {
    // Do invalid input logic
}

// Use long long if days>31
for (int K=0; K<days; K++)
    cout<<"Day "<<K<<": "<<(1<<K)<<"\n;
```

Here `1<<K` is 2^K

Alternatively, you can use a variable to save the payment
and shift it by 1 each iteration.